# Solve an ODE with positivity-preserving property unconditionally

Tags: ode, time-integration, implicit-methods

I have an ODE for a scalar function $u=u(t)$ of the form:
$$
\frac{du}{dt}=L(u).
$$
Here the function $L=L(u)$ satisfies:
$$
L(0)=0, \quad L'(u)\le0.
$$
Then it is easy to see that the solution $u=u(t)$ has the following property:

(i) If the initial value $u(0)\ge0$, then $u(t)\ge0$ for any $t>0$;

(ii) If the initial value $-M\le u(0)\le M$ with $M>0$, then $-M\le u(t)\le M$.

**Question**: I need to find a numerical method to solve this ODE and under **arbitrary** step size maintain the two properties or only one of two. I only know that the Euler backward method has these two properties. Does anyone of you know high order (e.g. third-order) methods to solve this problem?

Any links to literature or for further reading would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson The solution of an ODE has the property of monotonicity-preserving, i.e., if $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are solutions to the same ODE and $u(0)\le v(0)$, then $u(t)\le v(t)$ for any $t>0$. Since $u\equiv0$ is a solution to this ODE,  property (i) holds for both positivity-preserving and negativity-preserving with the aid of monotonicity-preserving property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The two properties are usually called positivity-preserving and monotonicity-preserving (makes it easier to find this question).
- Looking at http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2006-75-254/S0025-5718-05-01794-1/S0025-5718-05-01794-1.pdf and http://homepages.cwi.nl/~willem/DOCART/SIAM_HRS.pdf it seems that implicit Euler is the exception among implicit linear multistep methods in that only implicit Euler allows for timesteps to be arbitrary while preserving monotonicity (section 5.3). They say the restrictions on implicit linear multistep methods' timesteps are not much better than on explicit multistep methods.
- There is a discussion of monotonicity-preserving Runge-Kutta methods in Hairer-Wanner Vol.II, Section IV.11: implicit Euler is the only one among them having a threshold factor of $\infty$.
- See also http://www.cscamm.umd.edu/tadmor/pub/linear-stability/Gottlieb-Shu-Tadmor.SIREV-01.pdf, which discusses high-order strong stability-preserving methods and gives an overview of available methods (not unconditionally SSP, though).

Comment: There are also a more recent review and a book (disclaimer: I'm an author on both).  The review is here: https://www.brown.edu/research/projects/scientific-computing/sites/brown.edu.research.projects.scientific-computing/files/uploads/High%20Order%20Strong%20Stability%20Preserving%20Time%20Discretizations.pdf.

Comment: The result regarding backward Euler goes back to a 1979 paper of Bolley and Crouzeix (in French).

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answers! I just reviewed these literature briefly. In summary, it seems that there is NO ode solver which is greater than first-order and has the positivity-preserving and/or monotonicity-preserving property under arbitrary step size.

Comment: @Michael See also this paper (reference [79] in the review David Ketcheson linked to): http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~spijker/PUBLICATIONS-GENERAL/Spijker(1983)-Numer-Math-42-271-290.pdf

Comment: @Kirill Thanks for the reference. I went through this paper and found in Section 1.4 Remark in the first paragraph: the authors explained that, the contractivity property concerns arbitrary pairs satisfying (1.2) but not for some pairs of specific form. I think the conclusion in that paper does not completely rule out the existence of solver for the ODE in my problem.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I went through Bolley and Crouzeix's 1979 paper. They proved that: for systems of ODEs of the form $u'(t)+Au(t)=f$, there exists no ODE solver with rational form of $\Delta tA$ (i.e. including Runge-Kutta and multi-step methods) of order greater than 1. Here they made some assumptions on $A$ and $f$. However, my problem is a scalar ODE which is a special case of systems.